# Типизация данных которые были получены парсингом

Tags: python, парсер, requests, bs4

```
url = "https://minfin.com.ua/deposits/stats/"
response = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

maxdep = bs.find('td', class_="dtsvto-2 dVgcFk")
print(maxdep.text)

== 11.75
```

Проблема в том что к примеру:

```
maxdep = bs.find('td', class_="dtsvto-2 dVgcFk")
print(maxdep.text * 2) 

== 11.7511.75
```

Как сделать так чтобы maxdep стало числовым значением?

Comment: `float(maxdep.text.replace(",", "."))`

Comment: Огромное спасибо, все работает)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Преобразование типа с проверками:

```
if hasattr(maxdep, "text") and maxdep.text:
    num = float(maxdep.text.replace(",", "."))
```

PS при необходимости можно обернуть `num = float(maxdep.text.replace(",", "."))` `try: ... except ValueError:`